# Cross system transactions

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, transactions, windows-phone

I am probably using the wrong term here (would love the proper name if someone knows it) but I regularly run into the issue of wanting to save something to the database + something else. In my current scenario I have the following code.

```
public class Stock
{
    public Guid StockID { get; set; }        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
IEnumerable<Stock> stock = new StockService().Get();

using (Database db = DBFactory.Create())
{
    try
    {
        db.BeginTransaction();

        db.InsertAll(stock);

        foreach (Stock item in stock)
            IsolatedStorage.SaveFile(item.Name, item.Image);

        db.Commit();
    }
    catch
    {
        db.Rollback();
        throw;
    }
}
```

As you can hopefully tell what I'm doing is saving something to a database (in my case Sqlite) and to the IsolatedStorage on a Windows Phone device.

Now if the code as shown above fails it obviously leaves the `IsolatedStorage` in an inconsistant state. I can modify this code and delete any images from the IsolatedStorage in the catch block as such:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    db.Rollback();
    foreach (Stock item in stock)
        IsolatedStorage.Delete(item.Name);

    throw;
}
```

but I have run into this problem so many times and I can't help but feel there must be a better way. So is there some pattern that applies when you want to do something with a database in a transaction + do something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you put the `db.Commit();` before the `foreach` loop then any errors with the `Commit()` will be caught **before** the `foreach` gets executed. Only when `Commit()` is successful will the `foreach` loop run.

Comment: Thats fair BUT what happens when the database insert works fine and you've committed it but the IsolatedStorage save fails?

Comment: You are rolling back the changes to the db in the catch block and your `foreach` is essentially rolling back the changes to `IsolatedStorage`. I can't see a way to do it any easier but I await people's answers

Comment: Will your file storage component support the notion of TransactionScope?